# Animações e efeitos d rolagem em Javascript

Tags: javascript, animação

Nos últimos tempos tem sido comum encontrar sites animados baseados na rolagem da página. Mas, diferente do resultado de um WOW.js da vida por exemplo, Se você rolar, deixa o efeito ser executado, rolar para uma outra seção da página e voltar para o lugar anterior, o efeito é executado novamente.

Assim como também é possível encontrar elementos que se movem conforme você rola a página.

Alguém tem algum material de referência ESPECÍFICO, para o estudo desse tipo de animação?

Obrigado :)

Comment: Acho esta pergunta ampla demais. Podes juntar links a exemplificar as animações a que te referes?

Comment: Erick, não sei se você está falando daqueles efeitos de paralaxe, ou se está falando daquelas animações que disparam em certa posição da rolagem, ou se está falando de outra coisa. Tem como elaborar um pouco mais a pergunta para que a comunidade te ajude mais facilmente? Para acrescentar mais informações. basta clicar em [edit] embaixo da sua pergunta.

Comment: Sim. http://www.gv.com/2014/#exits
No momento só encontrei esse exemplo, vou procurar outros mais claros.
Mas me refiro exatamente a esse tipo de ação, esse "16 exits" se comporta de acordo com o ir e voltar na rolagem. Ele não acontece só uma vez, como no wow.js. 
Geralmente vejo esse efeito em títulos, e os desenvolvedores brincam com sua opacidade assim. Vou procurar outros exemplos para ser ainda mais claro.

Comment: http://codepen.io/bramus/pen/wayuh
Este é um belo exemplo. 
Gostaria de um material direcionado para análise.